# Problem with margins using amsart and geometry packages

Tags: margins, double-sided, geometry, amsart

I do not want different margins on even and odd sides, I just want the usual page setup from the `amsart` package. However, consider:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

compiling this with `pdflatex` gives different margins on odd and even sides. I think the problem is the combination of the `amsart` and `geometry` packages. If I do not use the `geometry` package it works fine. If I use `\documentclass{article}` it also works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the package `layout` you get a picture of the dimensions used by the `amsart` for laying out the page.  The following document reproduces that layout using the `geometry` package:

```
\documentclass{amsart}    

\usepackage[marginratio=1:1,height=584pt,width=360pt,tmargin=117pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}
\layout
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

In particular, the height and width specifications correspond to the `\textheight` and `\textwidth` produced by `amsart`.  The `marginratio` makes the marigns even, and `tmargin` moves the text down appropriately.

The value of `tmargin` was obtained as follows.  `layout` reports for `amsart` that `\topmargin=22pt`. To convert this to `tmargin` I added `1in = 72pt` plus `headheight=14pt` to the `22pt`. However, the resulting `layout` reported a `\topmargin` of `21pt`, so I bumped the result up by `1pt`, to get the required value. The `geometry` documentation says

> tmargin has nothing to do with \topmargin

but the package only provides `tmargin` to set the corresponding space.

All the above is assuming US latter paper.  The `amsart` class sets:

```
\headheight=8pt \headsep=14pt
\footskip=12pt
\textheight=50.5pc \topskip=10pt
\textwidth=30pc
\columnsep=10pt \columnseprule=0pt
\marginparwidth=90pt
\marginparsep=11pt
\marginparpush=5pt
```

and has

```
\DeclareOption{a4paper}{\paperheight 297mm\paperwidth 210mm
  \textheight 54.5pc }
\DeclareOption{letterpaper}{\paperheight 11in\paperwidth 8.5in }
```

So if you specify `a4paper` option then a different `\textheight` is used.  Again the `layout` package will report it for you.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. How did you calculate `tmargin=117pt` from the output of the `layout` package?

Comment: It seems that if I use the `a4paper` option (`\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}`) I get `height=632pt` instead of `height=584pt`..

Comment: Replies now included in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

The `amsart` class uses equal sized margins by default *and* the `twoside` option. However, When `geometry` realizes that the `twoside` option is in force, it uses a “2:3” ratio for the margins.

The text width set by `amsart` is 360pt independently on whether A4 or Letter paper is used. With `geometry`, instead, you get 430pt for Letter paper and 418.25pt for A4 paper.

If all you want is a larger text width, you can say

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[
  hmarginratio={1:1},     % equal left and right margins
  vmarginratio={1:1},     % equal top and bottom margins
  textwidth=400pt,        % new text width
  heightrounded,          % always useful
  %bindingcorrection=5mm,  % binding correction
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Don't specify `oneside` in the options for `amsart`, as this will affect the way the headers are set. The `vmarginratio` option is needed if you want the same look as `amsart`'s default, with equal upper and lower margins (header and footer not included).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the parameters of the package geometry to remove the difference between even and odd pages.
For instance, the following package declaration

```
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1]{geometry}
```

aims at defining the ratio between the different margins.

You can use hmarginratio or vmarginratio

Also,

```
\usepackage[top=4cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
```

permits to set the margins.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that `hmarginratio=1:1` gives a different page layout than that used by the `amsart` package.. For instance, it gives `height=556pt` and `width=430pt`.. Compare with the answer given by Andrew Swann.